# Measured in percentage OR percentages?

Tags: ielts

[image]

According to the chart above, I want to give it a description and wonder weather I should use percentage OR percentages in the following sentence.

> The bar graph shows 7 different reasons that adults choose to study, measured in **percentage/percentages**.

And what are the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A percentage" is a number expressed as a fraction of 100. So, just as you can refer to "numbers" in the plural, you can refer to *percentages* too. This is especially true where each percentage is a report metric in its own right, as in your example.

Your chart does not display just *one percentage* but rather *seven percentages*, so you are correct to use the plural in your description but I feel rest of the description needs more detail. You don't "measure" things in percentages - you *calculate* a percentage and then *display* them as such. Also, you should explain what these percentages represent. Were they the result of a survey, for example? If so, I would prefer:

> The bar graph shows 7 different reasons that adults choose to study and the number of people who stated these as their reasons, displayed as percentages.